# iOS window-based-app projects kill problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, xcode4

When I create a window-based-application (in Xcode 4, via simulator and iPhone device, even if don't add anything to the project or the window),

if I kill the app, when I open it again the view is frozen and when I click the home button it disappears into a black window and I can't do anything...

What is the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try resetting the simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if the application is running in background, it should be in your plist.
that will be a start, if the problem is still there u should post some of your code.

Comment: You mean to set 'Application does not run in background' to NO? I don't have this value at all, I've set it and it's still the same...

Comment: fine, show us some of your code otherwise it will not be easy to dig the bug out.
Assuming you are not doing any code at all and it still crashes - I suggest you to reinstalling the SDK ....

Comment: Thanks, yeah I've just created a new window-based and it crashed. Do you mean to reinstall Xcode or can I download the SDK by itself?